# Session based AES with random key and static salt

Tags: aes, cbc, salt

I'm currently using aes to encrypt/decrypt messages to and from a web service.

When the user establishes a session he sends a random  generated secret via rsa public key.

This secret is used to establish a secure channel using AES (CBC).

I'm using Rfc2898 to derive a key with a static salt (the salt is hardcoded and never changes). The IV is randomly generated for each message and prepended in cleartext.

Is it ok to use a static salt (Since I'm using a random generated secret for each session)?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing.  If the "secret" that is sent is uniformly random, and long enough, then there is no need to use a key derivation function.  That would be for if you had a password with less entropy than was nominally required for your encryption.  What are you hoping to accomplish using Rfc2898?

Comment: Also, it's unclear what you mean by generating random secrets via an RSA public key.

Comment: The secret is sent when establishing a session. Yes you are right, when I use a static salt there is kinda no use for a key Derivation function. Currently the secret was not long enough for the aes key, so I used a Derivation function.

@Stephen
I use a random function on the client to choose a secret which I then exchange with the server via rsa.

Comment: Why not just use Diffie Hellman?

Comment: I don't see that it makes any difference to my problem using diffiehellman instead of rsa.

Comment: Is this in addition to or instead of SSL?  Is the RSA key embedded in the application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you seem to be using a Password Based KDF (PBKDF); you are using PBKDF2, as defined in Rfc2898. You don't need to do this as randomly generated data is already fine for creating an AES key. So - as you don't need a PBKDF - you don't actually need a salt.

If you need more keys or key data then what is actually required is a Key Based KDF (KBKDF), as your shared secret already contains enough entropy. Passwords usually don't, that's why they require the key strengthening delivered by PBKDF (by using a salt and iteration count). HKDF doesn't *require* a salt either, but its security properties are significantly enhanced if you do provide a salt.

Note that CBC should not be used *by itself* to create a secure transport protocol. CBC does not provide integrity nor authenticity. And if error (padding) oracles apply - which is likely - then it doesn't even provide confidentiality, leaving you with nothing. You need to at least add a MAC - HMAC is preferred - and a MAC key. To generate two keys...see the second paragraph and provide two different labels (or "OtherInfo"), one for each key.